# how to differ between two canvas text elements with OnPointerEnter in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to differentiate between two text elements. If mouse hover one of this elements, it should change text and position. I read the documentation about `IPointerEnterHandler`, but can't understand how I can use canvas elements in one script to detect event with `IPointerEnterHandler`.

For help thanks a lot.

My script:

```
public class TextController : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler
{   
    public Text text1;
    public Text text2;
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (EnteringText1) // don t know exact if statement
        {
            text1.text = "i m entering text1";
            text1.transform.position = new Vector3(100f, 100f, 0f);
        }

        else if (EnteringText2) // don t know exact if statement
        {
            text2.text = "i m entering text2";
            text2.transform.position = new Vector3(100f, 100f, 0f);

        }
    }
}
```

My scene in Unity

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject` to get the name of GameObject the event occurred on. Since your `Text` GameObjects are named `text1` and `text2`, simply compare them against `eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name`.

```
public Text text1;
public Text text2;

public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    GameObject obj = eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject;

    if (obj.name == "text1")
    {
        text1.text = "i m entering text1";
        text1.transform.position = new Vector3(100f, 100f, 0f);
    }

    else if (obj.name == "text2")
    {
        text2.text = "i m entering text2";
        text2.transform.position = new Vector3(100f, 100f, 0f);

    }
}
```

If you just want to compare the value from the `Text` component then after getting the GameObject like I did above, use `GetComponent<Text>()` to retrieve the `Text` from it, check if it is `null` before retrieving its text value with `Text.text`

```
public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    GameObject obj = eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject;
    Text text = obj.GetComponent<Text>();

    if (text != null)
    {
        if (text.text == "EnteringText1")
        {
            text.text = "i m entering text1";
            text.transform.position = new Vector3(100f, 100f, 0f);
        }

        else if (text.text == "EnteringText2")
        {
            text.text = "i m entering text2";
            text.transform.position = new Vector3(100f, 100f, 0f);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

The script above must be attached to the parent Object of both `Text` components in order for it to detect events on its child Objects. In your case, this parent Object is named "Canvas".

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, aligning with Unity's philosophy, is to split the script into two, even though the event propagates upwards, you can intercept it at a lower level

Answer (score 0):

Just make script and call it something like `EnterableText`. Put this script on `GameObject` that contains `Text` component. The script itself should look something like:

```
[RequiresComponent(typeof(Text))]
public sealed class EnterableText : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    private static readonly Vector3 hoveredPosition = new Vector3(100f, 100f, 0f);

    public string defaultText;
    public string hoveredText;

    private Vector3 initialPosition;
    private Text textComponent;

    private void Awake()
    {
        initialPosition    = transform.position;
        textComponent      = GetComponent<Text>();
        textComponent.text = defaultText;
    }
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(100f, 100f, 0f);
        textComponent.text = hoveredText;
    }
    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = initialPosition;
        textComponent.text = defaultText;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you could put position of hovered text in a variable, to be able to easily adjust it during runtime.